# I got t the top 5 results from 2 tables. I wanted to know count of patients associated with the top 5 result

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is what I did but if i use the result of the top 5 , i get i different answer. What is the reason

```
SELECT COUNT(patient_id) as Patient_count 
FROM [DAassessment].[dbo].[sample_claims] 
WHERE procedure_code IN (SELECT code FROM [DAassessment].[dbo].[valid_cpt_codes] )
```

Comment: your subquery doesn't select 5 codes, so wy doy not try top 5 there first

Comment: Show us some example data and the expected result from that data